# How do I connect to a database using dreamweaver 2019?

Tags: mysql, database, dreamweaver

So I've recently created a website in Dreamweaver 2019, and I currently have a html form on it so the user can enter in their information. I wanted to know how can I connect to a database in Dreamweaver 2019. I don't see any panel to enter my database information. Is there even a panel in Dreamweaver 2019 to enter database information?

Comment: try this http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-set-up-the-mysql-connection-from-dreamweaver/